# Partitioning Tools

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning

I have just cloned a new hard drive for my Ubuntu machine using clonzilla. The problem I have is that I need to re size the boot partition because it cloned the drive exactly, which is good but what I want to do is make the main partition bigger, but it wont let me know matter what I'm using. So does anyone no of a partitioning software to help do what I want. I also want to do this because i would like to dual boot.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [gparted](http://gparted.org/) to resize your partitions.  It is in the Ubuntu repos.

The trick is, that you cannot resize a partition that is mounted. This is indicated by a key icon on the gparted screen.  So, if you wish to resize a partition that is in use on your current machine, you must boot into a live environment using a USB, and then perform your partition operations.  gparted is included in the Ubuntu live .isos for your convenience.

Comment: Ok. Cool thank you but i tried that but it still didn't seem to work but i will try it again and see if i did something wrong

Comment: If you can add a picture of the gparted screen to your question, we could give specific help.

Comment: Thank you for the help but i just decided to do it the hard way by just reinstalling it. thanks again